# Freemarker - Include Multiple templates inside config file

Tags: xml, freemarker, smooks

How can i include more than one template in Freemarker configuration file using Smooks?

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">

<params>
  <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
  <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
</params>

<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Response">
  <ftl:template>template1.ftl</ftl:template>
  <ftl:template>template2.ftl</ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
```

This doesnt seem to work. Throws an error at the second template line

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [example](https://github.com/smooks/smooks/blob/master/smooks-examples/freemarker-huge-transform/smooks-config.xml) you will see that each `ftl:template` tag should be inside `ftl:freemarker` tag. in your case:

```
<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Response">
  <ftl:template>template1.ftl</ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="Response">
  <ftl:template>template2.ftl</ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
```